# I can't get contacts from yahoo after jumping through all the OAuth loops

Tags: php, yahoo-api

I have go throught all the oauth loops, and When I make the call to get the contacts information I only get a 401 error.

this is my code:

```
<?php
//define yahoo consumer key
$yahoo_consumer_key = variable_get('_contact_grabber_yahoo_consumer_key',NULL);
define('YAHOO_CONSUMER_KEY', $yahoo_consumer_key);
//define yahoo consumer_secret
$yahoo_consumer_secret = variable_get('_contact_grabber_yahoo_consumer_secret',NULL);
define('YAHOO_CONSUMER_SECRET', $yahoo_consumer_secret);
//define yahoo callback
$yahoo_callback = variable_get('_contact_grabber_yahoo_callback',NULL);
define('YAHOO_CALLBACK', $yahoo_callback);
//define app id constant
$yahoo_app_id = variable_get('_contact_grabber_yahoo_app_id',NULL);
define('YAHOO_APP_ID', $yahoo_app_id);


$url = 
 'http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/'.$_SESSION['yahoo']['token']['xoauth_yahoo_guid'].'/contacts?';
$url .= 'oauth_consumer_key='.YAHOO_CONSUMER_KEY;
$url .= '&oauth_nonce='.sha1(time() + rand(0,10));
$url .= '&oauth_signature_method=plaintext';
$url .= '&oauth_timestamp='.time();
$url .= '&oauth_token='.$_SESSION['yahoo']['token']['oauth_token'];
$url .= '&oauth_version=1.0';
$url .= '&oauth_signature='.YAHOO_CONSUMER_SECRET;

$result = drupal_http_request($url);
dpm($result);

?>
```

This is the error:

```
<yahoo:error xml:lang="en-US">
 <yahoo:description>
  Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="signature_invalid", realm="yahooapis.com"
 </yahoo:description>
</yahoo:error>
```

I don't find nowhere how to fix this.
thanks

Oskar

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else ever stumbles on this, you cannot use plaintext for the api's, your signature has to be signed using HMAC-SHA1

Few good posts on here regarding how to do this, I would start here: [Oauth HMAC-SHA1 authentication to get contacts from Yahoo! Contacts API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259389/oauth-hmac-sha1-authentication-to-get-contacts-from-yahoo-contacts-api)