# Oauth HMAC-SHA1 authentication to get contacts from Yahoo! Contacts API

Tags: php, oauth, yahoo-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get contacts using Yahoo Contacts API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179189/get-contacts-using-yahoo-contacts-api)

I am developing a sysyem to get Yahoo contacts from users. I have completed all steps from http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html and I already got access token and token secret.

I am having problem to sign using HMAC-SHA1 algorithm, I have followed the steps from http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-signing.html to generate signing key but when I request contacts from a given user I get the error:

```
<yahoo:error xmlns:yahoo='http://yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng'
    xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yahoo:description>Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="signature_invalid", realm="yahooapis.com"</yahoo:description>
</yahoo:error>
```

Here is my code responsible to generate signing key:

```
$s =  'oauth_consumer_key='.rawurlencode($yahoo_consumer_key).'&';
$s .= 'oauth_nonce='.rawurlencode(uniqid()).'&';
$s .= 'oauth_signature_method='.rawurlencode('HMAC-SHA1').'&';
$s .= 'oauth_timestamp='.rawurlencode(time()).'&';
$s .= 'oauth_token='.rawurlencode($ouathToken).'&';
$s .= 'oauth_version='.rawurlencode('1.0').'&';
$s .= 'realm='.rawurlencode('yahooapis.com');

$baseString ='GET&'.rawurlencode('http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/'.$guid.'/contacts').'&'.rawurlencode($s);

$signingKey = rawurlencode($yahoo_consumer_secret).'&'.rawurlencode($ouathTokenSecret);

$signature = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $baseString, $signingKey, true)));

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true,
            CURLOPT_POST       => false,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/'.$guid.'/contacts'.    
                                  '?realm=yahooapis.com'.
                                  '&oauth_consumer_key='.$yahoo_consumer_key.
                                  '&oauth_nonce='.uniqid().
                                  '&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1'.
                                  '&oauth_timestamp='.time().
                                  '&oauth_token='.$ouathToken.
                                  '&oauth_version=1.0'.
                                  '&oauth_signature='.$signature
        ));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Anyone can help telling me where is the mistake? Have not I generated signing key correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using urlencode in some places instead of rawurlencode throughout which will use things like "+" instead of "%20" for a space. The Yahoo documentation (not so great for this area) shows the "normalized" Header/URL string using rawurlencode instead of urlencode. Other than the way you are encoding the request, it looks good.

*Edited: I had mixed up rawurlencode and urlencode. Rawurlencode uses RFC 3986 which is required by OAuth: http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#encoding_parameters

You are also double encoding $s! Don't do this - when creating $s don't use rawurlencode at all and than encode it when you build $baseString or URL Encode it at the top when you create $s but then DON'T encode it a second time in $baseString.

Comment: In this line: $baseString ='GET&'.rawurlencode('http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/'.$guid.'/contacts').'&'.rawurlencode($s); I must replace rawurlencode by urlencode? I have tried many ways but I still get the same error.. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'm sorry, I got it completely backward - EVERYTHING should be rawurlencoded, which uses RFC 3986. I got them mixed up. However, according to OAuth documentation, only reserved characters, per RFC3986, can be encoded and EVERYTHING else has to NOT be encoded. Look at http://oauth.net/core/1.0/ to make sure you have every step correct. I have edited my answer with the correct PHP Function - make sure you aren't mixing/matching raw/urlencoding and everything is uniform using rawurlencode();

Comment: Also, check your output to make sure there aren't any encoded characters that aren't part of the RFC 3986 reserved character list: PHP does some strange things sometimes with raw/urlencoding depending on your version: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html

Comment: Just edited again to include the part about double encoding $s - this will cause a problem. Make sure everything is encoded using RFC3986 and you are NOT encoding ALPHA, DIGIT, '-', '.', '_', '~' AND also make sure you are not double encoding anything. That'll fix it.